# How to do this kind of custom UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

[image]

I saw table view of an app  and would like to replicate this style, but have no idea of how to do this. Could you guide me how to make tableview show only cell with content like a UITalbeViewStyleGrouped, but with cell style like UITableViewStylePlain.

About custom footer cell like this I'm thinking of if statement in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

to use special xib for the footer. Is this the right idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that hard, as soon as you get the right places to do the work, and have some support from a graphic designer maybe. [This article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) is about exactly what you want to achieve. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will check this out look promising.